# How to configure maximum number of connections of MongoDB server on Windows?

Tags: mongodb

I need to run a Java program that have massive amounts of read requests from a Mongodb instance hosting on a Windows machine. How can I boost the speed to read?

I googled similar topics but they are all applid on Linux machines.

Answer (score 0):

Your tittle and the body doesn't fit. You may need to increase to TcpNumConnections and MaxUserPort but without providing server CPU, RAM , IO its hard to tell if your server can handle multiple connections. To boost the speed of read use sharding and improve your queries.